# Can iota.api.getTransfers() get specific transactions?

Tags: iota-network, javascript

According to iota.lib.js documents,

```
iota.api.getInputs(seed, [, options], callback)
```

the getInputs() have a options argument. options object have four members, *start*, *end*, *security* and *inclusionStates*.

i try to given the start value as 100.
i expect to show only these transactions which address key index is greater than 100.

However, it still displays all transactions.

Do I misinterpret this function?

---

For @mihi. Sure. please check the following code.

```
const IOTA = require('iota.lib.js');
const iota = new IOTA ({});
const dir = require('./directory.js');

iota.api.getTransfers(dir.ivy_seed, [{start: 100}], (e, s) => {
    console.log("trans:", s); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options argument is just an object, not an array (that goes for both getInputs and getTansfers).  It should work if you remove the square brackets.  The confusion is understandable since the [docs](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js#gettransfers) have square brackets around it, i have made similar mistakes.